# sftp put: how to prevent accidental overwriting of files

Tags: command-line, sftp

I am a long time user of FileZilla. Now for want of efficiency, I am switching to command line `sftp` from Linux desktop to a Linux server.

The `sftp put` command works perfectly fine for uploads. However, unlike FileZilla, there is no prompt of confirmation for overwriting an existing file on the server. I certainly fear any accidental overwrites. Is there a way to make `sftp` ask for confirmation before overwriting?

Comment: No, there's not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982128/4023950, same for sftp

Comment: That solution prevents overwriting any existing file. There may be cases where I                        want to deliberately overwrite some files. I was expecting a solution wherein I would get a prompt like "Would you want to overwrite existing? Y/N".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `put` command in `sftp` is not able to provide an interactive prompt to you for confirming the overwriting of an existing file. It assumes that you know what you are doing.

If you want to make sure that you upload files without overwriting existing files, use the `sftp` command `mkdir` to make a directory on the remote host and `cd` into it before uploading your files in that new and empty directory.

For example,

```
uploaddir=$( date +upload_%F )  # i.e. something like "upload_2020-05-18"

sftp remote <<END_SFTP
cd some/remote/path
mkdir $uploaddir
cd $uploaddir
put myfile
END_SFTP
```

The `mkdir` command would *fail* if there already is a directory with the same name as the one you're trying to create.  When `sftp` is running a non-interactive batch script, as above, the script would terminate at that point.